# What's the proper way to reference multiple functions for ontick event on asp timer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to have multiple functions called on an asp timer.  This is the code I've tried as this works with onclick events but I guess it's not the same for ontick event:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="30" ontick="Timer1_Tick(); Timer2_Tick();" ></asp:Timer>
```

This is the error I get:
CS1026: ) expected

What's the proper format for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way would be to call only one method, and have this method call all the methods you want.

If you need them to run at the same time, you should make them async, this way they'll run without slowing your program.

EDIT

Here is a small example :

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 method();
 anotherMethod();
 yetAnotherMethod();
}
```

And you can call the method by the code this way :

```
Timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
```

or this way :

```
 <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" runat="server" Interval="30" />
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?